# Rails 4: NameError uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, configuration, initialization

I've stored an array in `config/initializers/icons.rb`:

```
class Icons
  def self.emoticons
    emoticons = ['( o_o )', 'ʕ•ᴥ•ʔ']
  end
end
```

I assumed that I'd be able to access it with the following code from anywhere:

```
%p= Icons::emoticons.sample
```

or

```
%p= Icons.emoticons.sample
```

If I do that I get this error:

```
NameError in Tools#search
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Icons
```

What is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close: `Icons.emoticons.sample`

Comment: I've tried that as well and that gives me the same error... (Added to the question)

Comment: Ah, it's a new initializer (personally I'd make it a helper): restart the app.

Comment: You are a hero :) I truly would have used my entire day fixing a problem which needs no fix.

Comment: You might want to freshen up on the autload functionality in rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html